# Can not change Full name and Password of Jenkins user on High Sierra

Tags: jenkins, change-password, macos-high-sierra

I try set up Jenkins on Mac according http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/

But when I try set Full name to Jenkins User nothing happens,
And when I try reset password I see "Reset password failed." message.

With Sierra everething was OK, but after update, I think, some permission rules were changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With update macOS to 10.13.2 everything works